# How to set a null value to TimePicker?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, timepicker

I use the TimePicker and appear with a default value of "12:00 AM", I want to set the field in blank.

```
<TimePicker x:Name="timepicker" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create your own class of `TimePicker` that will allow a `NullableTime` on XAML.

The Class should be as following:

```
public class MyTimePicker : TimePicker
    {
        private string _format = null;
        public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create<MyTimePicker, TimeSpan?>(p => p.NullableTime, null);

        public TimeSpan? NullableTime
        {
            get { return (TimeSpan?)GetValue(NullableDateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value); UpdateTime(); }
        }

        private void UpdateTime()
        {
            if (NullableTime.HasValue) { if (null != _format) Format = _format; Time = NullableTime.Value; }
            else { _format = Format; Format = "pick ..."; }
        }
        protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
        {
            base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            UpdateTime();
        }

        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            if (propertyName == "Time") NullableTime = Time;
        }
    }
```

Then on XAML you should create your control and use it as below:

```
<local:MyTimePicker NullableTime="{x:Null}" />
```

If you use this sample you will see that the default value should be pick...

[image]

Comment: I change the last method because the propertyName must be "Time": protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
             if (propertyName == "Time") NullableTime = Time;
        }

Comment: You are right. If the answer resolves your issue, please mark the question as completed

Comment: What's the other solution? Because Xamarin said .Create<T, U> is already deprecated.